# Force relaunch of Finder from terminal into background

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

For some reason, Finder is no longer running and will not relaunch using conventional methods.

I can, however, get it running with the following command in the Terminal:

> `prompt$ open -g     /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder &`

Despite the fact that I'm ending the command with an ampersand and passing the `-g` flag to `open`, the resulting Finder opens attached to a completely new Terminal window that, when closed, causes the Finder application to also exit.

How can I relaunch the Finder from the Terminal, ensuring that it will run in the background without spawning a new shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The open command exits after it opens Finder. Even if it didn't, closing a shell would close background processes. You could try using disown:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder & disown $!
```

Or `launchctl submit`:

```
launchctl submit -l my.finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

`launchctl remove my.finder` removes the job.

Have you looked at log messages or crash reports? If you have tried to load or unload `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist`, try removing entries for Finder in `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd{,.peruser.501}/overrides.plist`.

Comment: `disown` worked like a charm.

Comment: & disown $! .. This answer saved my life.

Comment: Holy! You are a true hero!