# Heavy issues with Finder make iMac unusable

Tags: finder, imac, crash, performance

My iMac 2017 (i7 4.2 Ghz, 40 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD) ran very well for around two years. Unfortunately, not anymore: Lately, I have severe issues with the Finder and it – honestly! – drives me insane.

It all started with random Finder crashes/freezes and I always suspected that the network mounts were at fault. For example, sometimes Finder said that it was establishing a connection to a mounted drive and this alert never disappeared and froze the whole Finder.

I need mounted drives mostly with my Synology NAS (in LAN) and with WebDav (external). To try something, I switched from afp to smb on the Synology drive mounts, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Later, I suspected that the mess on the Desktop could be at fault. Yes, I have around 500 files on the Desktop which are mostly screenshots. I cannot imagine this to be a problem, but when Finder relaunched it felt laggy. Thus, I moved all files from Desktop to Downloads to make the Desktop empty again.

The Finder crash itself is truly fatal: When it happens, I can not restart the finder. I tried:

- Basic relaunch by click on the icon, Relaunch
- CMD+ALT+ESC, Relaunch
- Activity Monitor, Kill Process Finder
- Terminal, `killall Finder`

None of these solutions work. Finder stays closed. The only thing that relaunches Finder is this:

- `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder & disown $!` as hinted in [Force relaunch of Finder from terminal into background](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89958/force-relaunch-of-finder-from-terminal-into-background)

But when I do this, all windows reopen without being responsive. They are open and frozen in the same time. Then I try to do something in a window, the spinning mouse icon appears.

The issue is that bad, I cannot even reboot my Mac. Even if I reboot the Mac through the terminal, the iMac will not restart. I suspect it is trying to properly shutdown the Finder, but it cannot. So the shutdown or restart is frozen as well.

I can make the Finder work if I cut the power off from the Mac and start it again. Finder will work for a day or two and then making me mad again.

I am close to throwing away the Mac because reinstalling the whole system seems like a terrible overkill.

Any help is appreciated! I tried to describe my issues as accurate as possible. Sorry for the long issue.

Comment: You may want to look into another user on your computer to see if you still have the same problems. You could isolate if it’s system or user related. If it’s user related it could be a cache issue, maybe icons or spotlight related...

Comment: Welcome to Act Different!  Can you start your computer without connecting any network drive?? Just use your internal drive only and see if it works?

Comment: Launch in Safe Mode (hold shift at reboot) does that help? If a different user account as above does not work I would back up the Mac, reformat the drive and reinstall macOS. And BTW lots of stuff on the desktop eats resources. Keep it as clean as you possibly can.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will try your suggestions and come back, but it might take some time to be sure everything works again.

Comment: “Throwing away the Mac because an OS reinstall is overkill” is a huge overreaction.   It’s quite easy to do.  That said, you do have a Time Machine backup, right?

Comment: @Theologin this is a good idea. Maybe it is some user/Finder setting related to my account. I will try it and come back to the issue.

Comment: @jmh also a good idea, I will do that, maybe even disconnect internet for some time.

Comment: @SteveChambers what shall I do then in Safe Mode? Just try if I still get the issue?

Comment: @Allan of course, I was «joking». However, I still have a PC with Windows and Ubuntu and considering to switch (back) if this problem remains. Of course I have a Time Machine backup and even documents backuped seperately. No worries there at all. But if some config/setting is at fault, the Time Machine backup will not really help. I also suspect the issue might be related to Catalina since I never had it before the update.

Comment: @Andreas yes, just use your Mac  in safe mode somewhat normally for a reasonable time to see if  the issue re-occurs. https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201262 also, I suggest removing comments which say "I will try this". No issues if you take time to try and report. keep in mind there are multiple timelines at work, so 1-2 days are no big deal.

Comment: Please add Activity Monitor Screenshots if they show something using Disk, network, CPU, memory out of ordinary. IDK about energy tab.

Comment: If the system responds properly in safe mode, something that has been installed on the system is causing the issue. The fun part is finding out what as Login Items are only the **start** of what runs automatically...